# Devise not working for multiple domains on login - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have an application that respond to multiple domain, each domain must have different users so on the user model the validation for email look like:

```
validates_uniqueness_of   :email, scope: :domain_id, case_sensitive: false, allow_blank: true, if: :email_changed?
```

This allow me to register users with the same email on different domains, the problem is when one user is registered in one domain then the same user can login for ALL the domains in the platform. This is incorrect because the user only can login on the domain that he registered.

How can I have this working properly using Devise?

Comment: You will need to override devise session controllers create action. You can check for domain there and allow a user to login only if email is registered for that particular domain.

Comment: is not possible override some authentication method on Devise instead of do it on a controller?

Comment: Using the controller *is* the way to override default functionality. And you're going to want to do it in the registrations_controller.rb, not the sessions_controller as implied by Mandeep. Also, make sure that you're enforcing uniqueness at the database level by indexing user_id and domain_id together.

Comment: @marsatomic registrations controller is used for sign up not not sign in and OP is asking for sign in

Comment: @darkcode sorry didn't get you. Can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: @Mandeep I have resolved it overriding the method "self.find_for_database_authentication" as suggested on devise doc